# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jodatime

I have a problem with Joda Time and Hibernate, in my Spring application.
I currently use the following settings:

```
def springVersion = '3.2.12.RELEASE'
def hibernateVersion = '4.2.16.Final'
def jodaTimeVersion = '2.6'
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:$hibernateVersion"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:$hibernateVersion"
testCompile "org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.5.Final"
compile "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final"

compile "joda-time:joda-time:$jodaTimeVersion"
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1"
testCompile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA"
testCompile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:3.2.0.GA"
```

Everything runs smooth when compiling and deploying the app.
However, when i try to execut jUnit tests, i got the following error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator

Full stack trace is below:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:109)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:86)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:105)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:355)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [test_applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:924)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:120)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:102)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:246)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:69)
        at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:95)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:360)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:428)
        at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:246)
        at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:53)
        at org.hibernate.service.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:188)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildLifecycleControledServiceRegistry(Ejb3Configuration.java:935)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:290)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
        ... 75 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.integrator.UserTypeJodaTimeHibernateIntegrator
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:356)
        ... 87 more
```

Comment: You have multiple versions of the jadira jodatime library, one is compile time the other testcompile. Remove the old one and change testCompile to compile.

Comment: Thank you mr. Deinum for your reply. For some reasons, it seems to be working if i remove the following line: compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1" and change "testCompile" to "compile" for the last two joda time libs. Please repost your comment as an answer so that i can choose it as the best answer (since it solves my problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:2.0.1"
testCompile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA"
testCompile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:3.2.0.GA"
```

You have multiple versions of the jadira jodatime library, one is `compile` time the other `testCompile`. Which is strange to start with.

Remove the old one and change testCompile to compile.

```
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:3.2.0.GA"
compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.spi:3.2.0.GA"
```